# My car wasn not accelerating and finally come to stop

Tags: maintenance, chevrolet, motors

I have chevy lumina 1991. The motor is very clean and looks like and used to work like a brand new car. However, these days since I was getting broke , I had to wait till my gas meter is very low and fill the gas. After 2 weeks doing like that, my car started not working very well. For e.g the engine started well but it couldn't accelerate more than 5-10 mil/hr. Its like walking.

At some point of time, after a day, it worked and then the same thing happened and I tried to drove it like that for a mile and the car totally stopped. Now, nothing works. Even the electronic parts are down. No light, the motor doesn't start. Everything doesn't work.

What do you think is the problem?

Comment: At this time does anything work? Lights, horn, dash lights?

Comment: Nop. Not at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a number of things. A broken alternator belt would allow the engine to run until the battery gets so low it can't power the needed systems such as fuel pump,ignition, computers etc. At this point it would stop. You need to tell us what you have checked, what you are capable of checking and any visual clues such as the belts are in place, the battery has 12v etc. If nothing is working you need to start with the battery. Does any thing work if you attach jumper cables?

Comment: Okay. I took it to a Mechanic. The battery was dead. The starter had a problem. And the alternator was not working well. Guess what I bought replacement items which costed me around $300 for 1991 vehicle took it to the Mechanic and changed everything and the car started but still it couldn't accelerate. The Mechanic said its not getting the power and need to see the engine. He mentioned to me, it could cost me more.

So what I did was, returned all the items to the sellers, and Junk the car for $250. It's sad but no choice. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we could end up with a list of quesses that would be very long.  You really need to provide more information here.  Was the engine light coming on at any point?  Sounds like you may have multiple problems here.

The two weeks of not running right is interesting.  That almost sounds like fuel pump or clogged fuel filter issues.  Have you checked into that?

Comment: Okay. I took it to a Mechanic. The battery was dead. The starter had a problem. And the alternator was not working well. Guess what I bought replacement items which costed me around $300 for 1991 vehicle took it to the Mechanic and changed everything and the car started but still it couldn't accelerate. The Mechanic said its not getting the power and need to see the engine. He mentioned to me, it could cost me more. So what I did was, returned all the items to the sellers, and Junk the car for $250. It's sad but no choice. Thanks for the help –